# Android Track progress of Azure CloudBlockBlob upload

Tags: java, android, azure-mobile-services, azure-blob-storage

How can I print the number of bytes that have been uploaded after calling   `blob.upload(new FileInputStream(imageFile), imageFile.length());` I want to log something like "100/totalBytes bytes have been uploaded, 224/totalBytes bytes have been uploaded..." So I can create a progress bar of the upload progress.

this is the code:

//AzureBlobLoader extends AsyncTask

```
public class AzureBlobUploader extends AzureBlobLoader {
private Activity act;
private String userName;
private TaggedImageObject img;
private Fragment histFragment;

public AzureBlobUploader(Fragment f, Activity act, String userName, TaggedImageObject img) {
    super();
    this.act = act;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.img = img;
    this.histFragment = f;
}


@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

    File imageFile = new File(this.img.getImgPath());

    try {

        // Define the path to a local file.
        final String filePath = imageFile.getPath();

        // Create or overwrite the blob with contents from the local file.
        String[] imagePathArray = filePath.split("/");
        String imageName = imagePathArray[imagePathArray.length-1];

        System.out.println("Image Name: " + imageName);

        String containerName = userName + "/" + imageName;

        System.out.println("Container Name: " + containerName);

        CloudBlockBlob blob= this.getContainer().getBlockBlobReference(containerName);


        //UPLOAD!
       blob.upload(new FileInputStream(imageFile), imageFile.length());

        //-----DATABASE-----//
        //create client
        this.setDBClient(
                new MobileServiceClient(
                        "URL",
                        this.act.getApplicationContext()
                )
        );

        this.setImageTable(this.getDBClient().getTable(Image.class));
        this.setIcavTable(this.getDBClient().getTable(ICAV.class));

        //IMG TABLE QUERY
        String validImageID = containerName.replace("/", "_");
        Log.d("Azure", "Valid Image ID: " + validImageID);

        Image img = new Image(validImageID, this.img.getUser(), this.img.getLat(), this.img.getLon());
        this.getImageTable().insert(img);

        for(String context : this.img.getContextAttributeMap().keySet()){
            Map<String,String> attributeValueMap = this.img.getContextAttributeMap().get(context);

            for(String attribute : attributeValueMap.keySet()){
                String value = attributeValueMap.get(attribute);


                ICAV icavRow = new ICAV();
                icavRow.setImageID(validImageID);
                icavRow.setContextID(context);
                icavRow.setAttributeID(attribute);
                icavRow.setValue(value);

                this.getIcavTable().insert(icavRow);
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    return null;
}



@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... object) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(object);
    Log.d("progressUpdate", "progress: "+((Integer)object[0] * 2) + "%");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    // to do


}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see the Azure SDK doesn't directly allow for that, but it should be fairly easy to wrap your inputstream in another input stream that can give callbacks for bytes read. Something like that:

```
public class ListenableInputStream extends InputStream {

    private final InputStream wraped;
    private final ReadListener listener;
    private final long minimumBytesPerCall;
    private long bytesRead;

    public ListenableInputStream(InputStream wraped, ReadListener listener, int minimumBytesPerCall) {
        this.wraped = wraped;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.minimumBytesPerCall = minimumBytesPerCall;
    }


    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int read = wraped.read();
        if (read >= 0) {
            bytesRead++;
        }
        if (bytesRead > minimumBytesPerCall || read == -1) {
            listener.onRead(bytesRead);
            bytesRead = 0;
        }
        return read;
    }

    @Override
    public int available() throws IOException {
        return wraped.available();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        wraped.close();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void mark(int readlimit) {
        wraped.mark(readlimit);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void reset() throws IOException {
        wraped.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean markSupported() {
        return wraped.markSupported();
    }

    interface ReadListener {
        void onRead(long bytes);
    }
}
```

`minimumBytesPerCall` should be initialised with some sensible number, as you probably don't want to be called on every single byte, maybe every half a megabyte should be good.

And remember that this all gets called on the `doInBackground` thread, so act accordingly.

**edit:**

I've edited the class above, there was a small error on computing the `bytesRead` value.
The official documentation explains your follow-up questions https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read()

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream

So `read()` reads 1 byte of data (or return -1) if reached the end. So yes, it must be called several several times to read a whole image.

Then the method `onRead(long)` get's called every time at least `minimumBytesPerCall` have been read (that's to avoid of calling back for every single byte) and once more at the end of the stream (when it returns -1)

The value passed to `onRead(long)` is the amount that have been read since the last call. So implementing this on your AsyncTask you would have to accumulate this value and compare with the total size of the file.

Something like the following code inside your asynctask should work fine (assuming the `Progress` generic parameter is a Long):

```
    private long fileLength;
    private long totalBytes;

    private final ListenableInputStream.ReadListener readListener = new ListenableInputStream.ReadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRead(long bytes) {
            totalBytes += bytes;
            publishProgress(totalBytes);
        }
    };
```

and on inside your upload part you replace with:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
fileLength = imageFile.length();
ListenableInputStream lis = new ListenableInputStream(fi, readListener, 256 * 1024); // this will call onRead(long) every 256kb
blob.upload(lis, fileLength);
```

and as a last remark, remember that internally the `CloudBlockBlob` just caching the file on its own memory for later upload, or doing any other weird stuff that is out of your control. All this code does is check that the complete file was read.

happy coding!

Comment: ps.: I've just edited my answer to add necessary methods to a good wrapper implementation.

Comment: so to use it I would do blob.upload(new ListenableInputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile), x, y), imageFile.length()); I'm not sure how to use ReadListener and what I should pass for minimumBytesPerCall. Would I log the bytes read in the ListenableInputStream class in the read method?

Comment: ReadListener is an interface. You should read about interfaces in Java. You could just write `implements ReadListener` on your `AzureBlobUploader` and pass `this` keyword. The `ListenableInputStream.onRead(int)` will be called every time more bytes than `minimumBytesPerCall` gets sent. Read my comment about it at the end of the answer. Probably around 256k~512kb would be appropriate to not spam the UI thread and keep the progressbar moving.

Comment: @Budius I see your idea is right, but I searched two `ReadListener` interfaces. The one is a [JavaEE interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ReadListener.html) which not for Android, the another is a [third-party interface](https://datalogic.github.io/android-sdk-docs/reference/com/datalogic/decode/ReadListener.html) for decoder like Barcode. They seems to be not suitable for this case. Please point out which `ReadListener`. Thank!

Comment: I'm calling blob.upload(new ListenableInputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile), this, 500000), imageFile.length()); I'm implementing ListenableInputStream in AzureBlobUploader and implementing the onRead method. I get some numbers which I don't know how to use to get a percentage. Sometimes the printing stops and the image has not been uploaded and sometimes it keeps printing after the image has uploaded. I tried getting rid of the if statement in the read method and passing bytesRead to onRead and then doing (bytes/imageFile.length())*100 to get a percentage but I don't get reasonable nums

Comment: I need to understand what  int read = wraped.read();
        bytesRead += read;
        if (bytesRead > minimumBytesPerCall) {
            listener.onRead(bytesRead);
            bytesRead = 0;
        } is doing. In the end the goal is to be able to print x/totalBytes have been read or a percentage. does the read method get called multiple times? how many bytes does it read every time it's called. say it's 500, how can I print 500/total have been read, 1000/total have been read, 1500/total have been read, 2000/total ....

Comment: @JuniorDeveloper I've updated my question with a correction on the code (sorry!) and some extra explanations.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT the ReadListener is on the class itself. Scroll down a bit more, it's there `interface ReadListener`

Comment: I uploaded an image that was 8000 bytes as a result, I made minimumBytesPerCall=2000, If there is a 50k bytes image, it'll be called 25 times, if it's 3000 bytes it'll be called once. I made a few changes to the class and now everything is working. This is the code : https://pastebin.com/P89iG4LP and https://pastebin.com/t2UQhN0c . Thank you, you deserve a beer.

Comment: When all the bytes have been read, onPostExecute hasn't been called so it hasn't been uploaded so I just make the percentage 90% when it's supposed to be 100% and when onPostExecute gets called I make it 100%. It's not the most accurate accurate progress bar but it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way for your needs, there is a MS blog which introduce about [uploading a blob to Azure Storage with progress bar and variable upload block size](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2010/11/03/uploading-a-blob-to-azure-storage-with-progress-bar-and-variable-upload-block-size/). That code was written in C#, but it's very simple for reading by Java/Android Developer, I think you can easily rewrite it in Java for Android to compute the uploading processbar ratio to share via some public variables.

Hope it helps.